# SQL query to get the user, counting the minimum number of records

Tags: group-by, count

I have an table with some records and a column `LAST_EDIT_USER`.
If I want to select all users with the number of appearances for every user, I would do

```
SELECT   LAST_EDIT_USER,COUNT(LAST_EDIT_USER)
FROM     EDITED_ELEMENTS_TABLE
GROUP BY LAST_EDIT_USER
ORDER BY COUNT(LAST_EDIT_USER) ASC;
```

and this will return something like

```
NULL   0
user1  5
admin  7
USER2  11
```

How can I get from a SQL filter the **user1** (with the minimum of occurrences) - **excepting NULL**?
LATER EDIT: or a list of the users with minimum number of occurrences

Comment: Are you asking how to ONLY return 1 row which would be user1 because it has the minimum count where `LAST_EDIT_USER` is not null?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what happens if there are two users with the same lowest count (e.g.: user1 -> 5, user2 -> 5), return all of them or only one of them? If only one of them, what's the criteria which of them will be returned (e.g. lexicographical smallest user name)?

Comment: Yap, I need a list of the users with the minimum number of uses, sorry

Comment: *- excepting NULL?* - `HAVING last_edit_user IS NOT NULL`. *I need a list of the users* - it is necessary to specify DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause to filter the rows where `last_edit_user` is null. Then put another query around it, to get the minimum count. Use this as a subquery in the `HAVING` clause to get only the ones with the count equal to the minimum.

```
SELECT last_edit_user,
       count(last_edit_user)
       FROM edited_elements_table
       WHERE last_edit_user IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY last_edit_user
       HAVING count(last_edit_user) = (SELECT min(c)
                                              FROM (SELECT count(last_edit_user) c
                                                           FROM edited_elements_table
                                                           WHERE last_edit_user IS NOT NULL
                                                           GROUP BY last_edit_user) x);
```

Comment: do it needs an AS.... ? because it gives me an error.

Comment: @WDrgn - try putting a table alias between the last 2 parenthesis - `GROUP BY last_edit_user) a );`

Comment: @WDrgn: Sorry, I missed to alias the subquery, you're right. I correct the answer, thanks for the pointer.