# How do I select all rows with minimum count number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a customer table that contains the name of the customer and an order type represented by an int.
If I try to count each customer with order = 4 with this query :

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_NAME,
    COUNT(*) AS CUSTOMER_Count
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
WHERE CUSTOMER_ORDER = '4'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

the output will be like this

| Customer Name | Name count |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Alice | 2 |
| Bob | 3 |
| Charles | 3 |
| David | 1 |

I would like to Get `Customer Name` and `Name count` for each Customers that have the minimum count
The output would be like this

| Customer Name | Name count |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| David | 1 |

I have try this query

```
SELECT MIN(CUSTOMER_Count)
FROM(
    SELECT
        CUSTOMER_NAME,
        COUNT(CUSTOMER_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_Count
    FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ORDER='4'
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME
);
```

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `SELECT TOP (1) * FROM (SELECT ...) c ORDER BY CUSTOMER_Count` maybe? Your question lacks proper sample data.

Answer (score 0):

for your following questions I suggest you read Erik Darling and Marcello Miorelli's articles first so you know how to provide proper sample data.

The following would return the needed values:

```
SELECT
         CUSTOMER_NAME,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     CUSTOMER_TABLE
WHERE    CUSTOMER_ORDER = '4'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME
HAVING   COUNT(*) = (
                       SELECT MIN(c)
                       FROM   (
                                 SELECT   COUNT(*) c
                                 FROM     CUSTOMER_TABLE
                                 WHERE    CUSTOMER_ORDER = '4'
                                 GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME
                              ) x
                    );
```

Which is a same solution as used in
[SQL query to get the user, counting the minimum number of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211230/sql-query-to-get-the-user-counting-the-minimum-number-of-records)